# Replace CKEditor toolbar images with font awesome icons

Tags: ckeditor, font-awesome

Is there some way to replace the default toolbar images (e.g. Bold, Italic, etc.) with Font Awesome icons?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old issue, but on a plugin by plugin basis I've been able to add font-awesome icons to ckeditor buttons with the following code inside the plugin's `init` function.  In my case my plugin was called `trim`:

```
//Set the button name and fontawesome icon
var button_name = 'trim';
var icon = 'fa-scissors';

//When a ckeditor with this plugin in it is created, find the button
//in the current instance and add the fontawesome icon
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event) {
  var this_instance = document.getElementById(event.editor.id + '_toolbox');
  var this_button = this_instance.querySelector('.cke_button__' + button_name + '_icon');
  if(typeof this_button != 'undefined') {
    this_button.innerHTML = '<i class="fa ' + icon + '" style="font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome !important;"></i>';
  }
});
```

It hinges on knowing the class of the span inside the button, so it might not be the most convenient but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is you can use Bootstrap theme on CKEditor or you can use [Froala](http://editor.froala.com/) editor,It has inbuilt image uploader

Comment: It's not about to upload image, it's about to replace toolbar icons with Awesome Icons.