# set plugin toolbar icon using class names in CK Editor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

How do I set plugin and/or widget toolbar button icon using class names (instead of using image URL)?

Comment: Not totally sure I understand the question, but I used this tip http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363283/5914789

Comment: That was very close to what I'm trying to do, except that I only need it for a new button from my plugin. Does that mean that there's no official way of doing this? For example, I was expecting something like ```CKEDITOR.plugins.add("myplugin", { className: "fa fa-scissors", ...}``` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a hack for this seemingly obvious missing feature:

```
editor.ui.addButton('MyButton', {
    //className: '...' // this only adds the classes to the parent container, not the icon span
    icon: '_ fa fa-scissors _'  // this hacks the existing classes and injects extra classes to the icon span
});
```

Tested with CK Editor v4.6.2

Comment: that is simple! never thought of doing it that way.