# Set icons for CK Editor context menu using Font Awesome

Tags: ckeditor

After figuring out a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41630183/564274) for setting toolbar icons to use classes from Font Awesome, I'm now stuck again with setting icons for context menu items. The hack won't work since the whole context menu panel is in a separate iframe, and the icons are not loaded.

How do I set icons for context menu items to use class-based images?

Comment: Have you tried to include font awesome into ckeditor like https://jsfiddle.net/svmxg5qt/ ? Have not tested with context menu but works for content.

Comment: It didn't work. Looking at https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/d136bb7822457363b2d7fd85a9abe86471185096/plugins/menu/plugin.js#L163, it seems to load only the editor.css defined in the skin.

Comment: shot in the dark, but maybe add @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"); to editor.css

Comment: Hah! That should do the trick. I was digging more into the hack on the javascript site to inject the extra CSS file, and didn't think of the simple CSS import.

Comment: I had to add another line at the end to override the font rule: `.fa{font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;}`